# Opening the brackets of a column matrix (vector)

Tags: matrices, vectors

I found some writing of opening column matrix (vector):

$\sum_{j=2}^4\begin{pmatrix}4\\j\end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2^4} = 6\times \frac{1}{2^4}+4\times \frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^4}$,

it is a bit unclear, how can I transform the column matrix (vector) to just a number.

Comment: That expression represents binomial coefficients, not a vector

Comment: this is not a vector, it is "n choose k": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: @DavidSheard, ah, now it is clear, thank you!)